# Never ending deployment on Azure ACS Kubernetes

Tags: azure-container-service

Any idea to have a running kubernetes on Azure?

I try the deploy with the Azure UI and after 49 minutes 6 secondes the deployment is still running.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment should take 5 to 10 minutes.  There are three reasons why the deployment may take longer:

1. Service principal is not setup correctly: https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/serviceprincipal.md
2. There is a platform issue with the VM or extension.
3. If you are using windows, the image may not be provisioning.

Try the deployment again, and if it falls in reason #2 or #3, please submit an incident through the portal.  If you suspect different than #1-3, please submit an issue through https://github.com/azure/acs/issues.

Comment: After 2 retry the kubernetes cluster finally start. Thanks.